# ListActivity Values are Objects, Want to Display Strings

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity that is currently displaying a list of type Data objects. These type Data objects have custom data:

```
String title;
```

The following is in my ListActivity constructor:

```
List<Data> values = dataInterface.getAllData();

ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The application displays on screen all the Data objects without error.

The problem is that the text displayed for each list item is:

```
Data@42731008
Data@427362c0
```

and so on.

I understand these are the object id's of the Data objects. Instead, I want to display the Strings found in Data.title. I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: I think Data class must have a getter and setter methods inside it right?

Comment: If you have Model class then need to use `yourArrayList.get(position).getTitile()`. and if you have no any such class need to use `toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a custom Adapter, then define the `public String toString()` method in your `Data` class as follows:

```
public String toString {
   return title;
}
```

It will be used by the ArrayAdapter when it represents the object in the ListView.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is this considered to be hackish?

Comment: IMO no, it is the purpose of `toString()` to return a representation of the object as a `String`. Android's predefined Adapters have no way of knowing exactly which attributes of an object to display, so they display the object itself, relying on `toString()`. If `toString()` is not set, then the implementation from the parent `Object` class is used, which is `ClassName@instanceId`. If you want a better representation of your object, define a custom adapter and do what you want in the `getView()` method.

Comment: I dont think this is the best way because sometimes you will have multiple String in your class, like "author name" and "title" (no offense, i upvoted your answer).

Comment: Sure, in such case you need a custom adapter. You also need a custom adapter when you want a custom layout, with more than just text. If OP just wants to display the title and keep a simple layout, then my solution is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter :

```
holder.myTextview.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
```

The point is in the `getItem(position).getTitle()`, because your custom adapter extends `ArrayAdapter<Data>`, `getItem(position)` will return an instance of `Data`.

After that, you just need to get the title from the `Data` using `getTitle();` (**depends** on your setter - getter in you `Data` class).

Just comment if you dont understand something or if i miss understand you :)