# How to print the data table in SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I do not know how to print the data table which stores in SQLite on Android

First, I write the data base file:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Localization";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "RSSIMAP";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "device_name";
    private static final String KEY_RSSI = "RSSI";
    private static final String KEY_DIST = "distance";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "time_stamp";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RSSI + " TEXT," + KEY_DIST +" TEXT,"+ KEY_TIME +" TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    } 

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getDeviceName()); // device name
        values.put(KEY_RSSI, contact.getRSSI()); // RSSI
        values.put(KEY_DIST, contact.getDistance()); // 
        values.put(KEY_TIME, contact.getTime());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_RSSI, KEY_DIST,KEY_TIME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setDeviceName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setRSSI(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setDistance(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setTime(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getDeviceName());
        values.put(KEY_RSSI, contact.getRSSI());
        values.put(KEY_DIST, contact.getDistance());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, contact.getTime());
        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
         new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Then, i have inserted some rows in the database, but I still need to write a activity to print the table, But I am confused how to write it (use Gridview or Listview ?) .. Thanks a lot

```
public class Display extends Activity   {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    DatabaseHandler ins_rssi_dis = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);


          List<Contact> contacts = ins_rssi_dis.getAllContacts();       


    }
```

Then, I use the ListView to display data

```
 public class Display extends ListActivity   {

        DatabaseHandler datasource = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        List<Contact> datadisplay = datasource.getAllContacts();
        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datadisplay);

        ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

But the results are not correct, such as:

Contact@41e5cd78
Contact@41e65ec8

I guess the getAllContacts() methods is incorrect, but I am not sure ...

The activity_display.xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Display" >

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's depends on your data, but i think you need `ListView`, you must read documentation and see which one is better for you

Comment: print as in you want to print them in a LOG? or want to show them on screen?

Comment: What you have tried to print

Comment: It can print well in a LOG, but on the screen, it cannot work

Comment: I explained the solution for the exact same problem (Contact@41e76...) in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26728067/2914666, provided as an answer here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see `Contact@41e5cd78 Contact@41e65ec8` because you are displaying `Contact` objects as Strings.

Implement the `toString()` method in the `Contact` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.firstName+" "+this.lastName; // example
}
```

If everything else in your code is OK (I haven't checked), you will see the first name and last name of each contact in your list view.

Answer (score 0):

similar tutorials are here :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

they are using ListView , and your data to be printed also looking same, if you are going with this, you may needed to write an **adapter class** in addition to your Activity class.
also have two xml Layouts for display ListView and To display ListItem in the ListView

Here is the sample code for you: try it , i hvn't tested this, may have some correction, but the idea is there.

the **ContactListAdapter** class:

```
public class ContactListAdapter {

private final Activity context;
List<Contact> contactAdapter = new ArrayList<Contact>();

public ContactListAdapter(Activity context,List<Contact> contactlist) {

        super(context, R.layout.download_item, downloadList);
        this.context = context;
        this.contactAdapter = contactlist;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.cotact_item, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    TextView txtTitle3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item3);
    TextView txtTitle4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item4);
    TextView txtTitle5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item5);

    txtTitle1.setText(contactAdapter[position].getId());
    txtTitle2.setText(contactAdapter[position].getName());
    txtTitle3.setText(contactAdapter[position].getRssi());
    txtTitle4.setText(contactAdapter[position].getDistance());
    txtTitle5.setText(contactAdapter[position].getTime());


    return rowView;
}
}
```

the **Display** class

```
public class Display extends ListActivity   {

    DatabaseHandler datasource = new DatabaseHandler(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    List<Contact> datadisplay = datasource.getAllContacts();

//        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datadisplay);

    ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(Display.this, datadisplay);

    ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

the **activity_display.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context=".RecentActivity" >
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/main_download_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**contact_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android: android:orientation="vertical"      

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="id" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="name" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="rssi" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="distance" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="time" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: I use the ListView to display, but the results are "@41e5cd78.."  I think my getAllContacts() method might be wrong .... But I am not sure ...

Comment: have you tried to print the result to console or Logcat? How you are passing these datas? please post those codes for reference. hope the problem with passing arguments to adapter clas..if using, not the value of String object is returned!

Comment: I just print it on the tablet, I do not know how to print it on log cat or console... other method such as insert, update seem well, only the print cannot work..

Comment: ok, you can use Log.d("value", value); plese post your code, then I can figure out whats happeing...

Comment: Thank you :) I post the codes above for your review

Comment: where is your adapter class?? you are passing Object: Contact instead of passing String! you need to use a custome adapter class to do this.

Comment: @swing you have trying to write object value, so you see that value, for solving that problem override toString() in your class and return each value that you want to print

Comment: can you put your activity_display.xml here, i will do it for u.

Comment: hi, @shayan pourvatan  how to override toString() .. I still feel confused..if possible, could you show me the codes how to correct ? THX

Comment: go to `Contact` class, write like `@Override
 public String toString() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return title;
 }`

Comment: @user3737266  I have added the .xml file for your review